# NA p-value in R cor.test

Tags: r, nonparametric

$R$ gives "NA" for the p-value when I try to run Kendall's test with an "exact p-value" flag set on a larger data set (n=170 seems to be the cutoff). Is this just a computation problem or something deeper? Spearman's test with an exact p-value flag set returns a p-value.

````
cor.test(sample(1:200),sample(1:200),method='kendall',exact=TRUE)

         Kendall's rank correlation tau

 data:  sample(1:200) and sample(1:200)
 T = 10905, p-value = NA
 alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
 sample estimates:
       tau
 0.0959799
```
````

Comment: The approximation is close for large $n$.  For example, if you were to start with something like `set.seed(2022);n <- 170;A <- sample(1:n);B <- sample(1:n)` then `cor.test(A,B,method='kendall',exact=TRUE)` gives `p-value=0.08651` while `cor.test(A,B,method='kendall',exact=FALSE)` gives `p-value=0.08626`

Comment: @Henry My qualm with the approximation is I couldn't tell from the man page what it was based on...if it's a CLT approximation, then my data might not be good for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's a computational issue to do with how `cor.test` calculates the p-value for `method = "Kendall"`.

If you have a look at lines 92 - 108 of the [source code for `cor.test`](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/cor.test.R), you'll notice that it calls `stats:::C_pKendall` to calculate the p-value.

If you then dig further and have a look at the [source for `C_pKendall`](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/src/kendall.c), you'll notice that there is a division term with a denominator of `gammafn(n + 1)` in line 96. Now `gamma(n)` returns `Inf` for `n >= 172` (for integer valued `n`) in `R`, so I suspect this division terms ends up becoming `Inf / Inf = NaN` for `n = length(x) >= 172`, resulting in a p-value of `NaN`.